# Unable to get ad preview using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the information from this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/previews/) to generate iframe of the ad preview (in Facebook Graph API),

According to the documentation, we need to use the following URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{adgroup-id}/previews/ad_format=
```

Not able to understand how to pass in the `ad_format`. It is compulsory to pass this parameter.

Comment: The docs you linked explain that ad_format must be one of `RIGHT_COLUMN_STANDARD`, `DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD`, etc.  What do you need to know about this field?

Comment: Yeah, I tried passing one of these but came across the following error,

"error": {
    "message": "Unknown path components: /ad_format=DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,

Answer (score 0):

`GET` parameters are passed like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{adgroup-id}/previews/?ad_format=DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old. But in order to run a preview you need to pass two parameters:

1. ad_format
   There are various types of ad_formats: You generally use them according to your specific use. For basic mobile and desktop testing 
   DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD, MOBILE_FEED_BASIC, MOBILE_FEED_STANDARD, MOBILE_FULLWIDTH will work fine
2. access_token

So your URL will be of the format :

https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/AD_ID/previews?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&ad_format=DESKTOP_FEED_STANDARD